# Setting custom system-property for Payara Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, payara

I am new to Docker and trying to create a Payara image for my application.
In that, I need to set a bunch of custom system-properties as server configs...like I have them in my Payara domain.xml:

```
<configs>
    <config name="server-config">
      <system-property name="com.myorg.config.propertyA" value="abc"></system-property>
      <system-property name="com.myorg.config.propertyB" value="def"></system-property>
      .....
      ......
      .......
```

So far, the Dockerfile I wrote, is like this.
I am trying to set just one system-property as of now, to experiment with ..and it's not working:

```
FROM payara/server-full
COPY myapp.war $DEPLOY_DIR
RUN echo 'set configs.config.server-config.system-property.com.myorg.config.propertyA=abc' > $POSTBOOT_COMMANDS
```

If I look at the *post-boot-commands.asadmin* inside the running container, it looks like this:

```
set configs.config.server-config.system-property.com.myorg.config.propertyA=abc
deploy /opt/payara/deployments/myapp.war
```

My application WAR ultimately fails to deploy due to being unable to find the property '*com.myorg.config.propertyA*'.
I think I am trying to set the system property in the wrong way. Can anybody please advise? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I found this works in the Dockerfile.
(So, I was trying to set it the wrong way initially).

```
RUN echo 'create-system-properties com.myorg.config.propertyA=abc' > $POSTBOOT_COMMANDS
```